# icon to byte [] C# compact framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I've looked around for an answer to this for quite some time.

I need to convert an icon to a byte[] in .NETCF but there is no icon.save() function in compact framework to create a MemoryStream object.  What is another way that I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things I can think of, one of them is suggested by Christian, the other one is that if it is a resource, can't you get a ResourceStream? This works if you make the icon an Embedded Resource (example found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292))

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388052/resource-from-assembly-as-a-stream) also discusses something not unlike your problem.

Comment: The resourcestream is what I needed since they are each different filetypes and not in .ico format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to call Icon.ToBitmap() and then read the bytes from the bitmap?

Comment: Unfortunately no :/ There's no methods within the compact framework's Icon class to do a ToBitmap() or Save()...

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the raw bytes of the .Ico file then you can just read it directly with a file stream