# WPF C# How to Properly use the Embedded Resource in this scenario

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application. It references a word document template and using the DocX library it replaces certain strings with data that is entered into the application. It then uses the DocX library to create a new word document.

My question is two fold right now I am using a static path. I want to make it so that the template is embedded in the application and the new document is put into a specific folder regardless of the root folder when the application is deployed.

Currently my code looks like this

```
string fileNameTemplate = @"C:\HEO_Proposal_Tool\FinalDocs\HEO-Proposal-{0}-{1}.docx";
string compName = CompName;
string jciName = JciFName + " " + JciLName;
string outputFileName = string.Format(fileNameTemplate, compName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
DocX letter = DocX.Load(@"C:\HEO_Proposal_Tool\TemplateDoc\Sales_HEO Sample Budgetary Proposal.docx");
```

First off is the embedded resource the right method for what I want to do? And if so how would I use it in this scenario.

Thank you

Comment: Which methods `DocX` have to load? If it must to be a file on a disk, then you can extract your template into temp folder and then load it from there at least. If there is a method to supply it a stream, then [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1388052/1997232).

Comment: Not quite sure what you are saying here. Are you asking what methods does the DocX library use to load the document and if those resources will accept a stream type as an input source?

Comment: Add a folder to your project and drag yourfile.docx  to it then you can get it like this :  `var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/yourfile.docx");`  
...