# How to play a video resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I put my files in the resource list

I use visual studio so I went to the Project **Property > Resource Tab > Select file options> Add resource> Add Existing File ...**

I want to keep my files private so I thought of using something like

```
string temp = "~tempv.dat";
File.WriteAllBytes(temp, Properties.Resources.MyVideo);
```

Now how can I do the following with my tempv.dat file

- How can I reproduce it?
- How can I put it in the temporary windows folder
- How can i remove it when closing wpf

My Xaml Code:

```
<MediaElement Name="myVid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

Comment: It should be possible to obtain [resource as a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1388052/1997232) instead of using files. Not sure if `MediaElement` can play stream, in worst case you have to use some library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your media file to project as ***embedded resources***. This is easier because of it is necessary to know the file extension when saving to disk. The `MediaTimeline` elements requires the file extension, does not support a stream.
Then extract audio/media content from a resources and write it to the temporary file. Then set *URI* for the `MediaTimeline` source to make reference to the temporary file.

Code behind:

```
 private string MediaFilePathName { get; set; }

 var resourceName = "[YourAssemblyName][.Folder].Movie.mp4"; // NOTE: Case sensitive
 using (var fstream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
 {
      var ext = resourceName.Substring(resourceName.LastIndexOf("."));
      var pathfile = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
      using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(pathfile, FileMode.Create))
      {
          fstream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
      }
      media.Source = new Uri(pathfile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
      MediaFilePathName = pathfile;
  }
```

In the XAML:

```
<Window ...  Closed="Window_Closed">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="audio">
            <MediaElement.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <MediaTimeline x:Name="media" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </MediaElement.Triggers>
        </MediaElement>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The temporary file should be deleted when it no longer needed:

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(MediaFilePathName))
    {
        File.Delete(MediaFilePathName);
    }
}
```

Another way to use third party library that will execute all the steps.

Comment: The code works fine, but if the user is in the temporary folder he will find the media with a name similar to `325ae577-9f90-4c6f-9c73-2009a301168c.mp4`

Is there any way I can leave this media in a .dat format?

Comment: @pablo kentch: Unfortunately no. It looks like `MediaElement` it uses file extensions to determine which filter is needed to play it. But it is possible, for example, to use `Windows.Closed` event to remove it. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @pablo kentch: Perhaps you should check possibility to save files under [Isolated storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage). Using isolated storage enables to store data in a manner that is controlled by the computer's security policy.

Comment: understand it is a pity not to accept other formats, Thanks for the beautiful explanation Jackdaw

Comment: @pablo kentch: Actually I haven't used, just read it. You can look at it in the documentation:  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage)

Comment: Thank you very much